# Firebase deleting value not working properly

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete the post of the current user or current uid. The uid of the user who posted is specified in the JSON by the String: uid. So i search for the uid in the snapshot, and if it exists i delete the parent of that uid. The problem is that all posts get deleted instead of just the one with the current uid stored.

JSON tree

```
Posts
    -LBzjsl0Yfwdyh9xg6D2 (this is random uid)

           photoUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blo..."

           uid: "BBPHwd0RRibXFCvHcXA2aKbHoTm1" (this is uid of the current user)
```

Code:

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

databaseRef.child("Posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: user).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


            if snapshot.exists() {


            //find out parent of current post
                let parent = snapshot.ref.parent!.key
                let ref = Database.database().reference()
                print (parent)
                func remove(child: String) {
                    ref.removeValue { error, _ in

                    }
                }
                remove(child: parent)
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain a bit better what the parent and the child is? Also what exactly are you trying to remove and what gets removed instead?

Comment: Please review these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help clarify your question.

Comment: I want to delete the post of the current user or current uid. The uid of the user who posted is specified in the JSON by the String: uid. So i search for the uid in the snapshot, and if it exists i delete the parent of that uid. The problem is that all posts get deleted instead of just the one with the current uid stored.

Comment: Have you tried removing the child instead of the parent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a child from Firebase (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749130/how-to-delete-a-child-from-firebase-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So your `snapshot` variable holds a list of results. The parent of that *list* is the `Posts` node. So if you delete the parent, all nodes will be removed.

To remove only the nodes matching your query, you need to loop over the `snapshot`'s child nodes, and delete those:

```
databaseRef.child("Posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: user).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  for child in (snapshot?.children)! {           
    (child as AnyObject).ref.removeValue()  { error, _ in
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is that the complete code block i need to use or do i pass in a value into the removeValue()? Because when i copy it gives me a an error "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'DataSnapshot'"

Comment: Ah. No value is needed for `removeValue()`. But it might be `ref?` and/or `child?`.

Comment: I changed it to:       for child in (snapshot.children) {
                    child.ref.removeValue()  { error, _ in } }
But i still get the error on the child value"Value of type 'Any' has no member 'ref'"

Comment: Well apparently swift debugger fixed the value problem so the code looks like this now: for child in (snapshot.children) {
                    (child as AnyObject).ref.removeValue()  { error, _ in
                    }
                }
Which worked perfectly!

Comment: What i dont understand is how the loop deletes only the values i want to delete? i didnt pass in any specific value..?

Comment: Your query gives you a snapshot of all child nodes that matching your `uid` filter. Since you're calling `removeValue` on the specific child nodes, it deletes those child nodes.