# I want to add a delete post button

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Premise**

I use firebase to manage posts, but I can not make posting delete function implemented.

**Code**
Swift4 postApi

```
    import Foundation
　　　import FirebaseDatabase

class PostApi {
    var REF_POSTS = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    var REF_MY_POSTS = Database.database().reference().child("myPosts")

    static var shared: PostApi = PostApi()
    private init() {
    }

    func observePosts(completion: @escaping (PostModel) -> Void) {
        REF_POSTS.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            let newPost = PostModel(dictionary: dic, key: snapshot.key)
            completion(newPost)
        }
    }

    func observePost(withPostId id: String, completion: @escaping (PostModel) -> Void ) {
        REF_POSTS.child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
            let newPost = PostModel(dictionary: dic, key: snapshot.key)
            completion(newPost)
        }
    }

    func observeMyPosts(withUid uid: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        REF_MY_POSTS.child(uid).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            let postId = snapshot.key
            completion(postId)
        }
    }

    func fetchCountPosts(withUid uid: String, completion: @escaping(UInt) -> Void) {
        REF_MY_POSTS.child(uid).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            let postCount = snapshot.childrenCount
            completion(postCount)
        }
    }

    func observeLike(withPostId id: String, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
        REF_POSTS.child(id).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            guard let value = snapshot.value as? Int else { return }
            completion(value)
        }
    }


            guard let dic = snapshot?.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            guard let postId = snapshot?.key else { return }
            let updatedPost = PostModel(dictionary: dic, key: postId)
            onSuccess(updatedPost)
        }
    }

    // 投稿を読み込んで好きな順に並べ替える
    func observeTopPost(completion: @escaping(PostModel) -> Void) {
        REF_POSTS.queryOrdered(byChild: "likeCount").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            let arraySnapshot = (snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]).reversed()

            arraySnapshot.forEach({ (child) in
                guard let dic = child.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                let post = PostModel(dictionary: dic, key: snapshot.key)
                completion(post)
            })
        }
    }
```

**Code**
Swift4 userApi

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class UserApi {
    // Adresse Datenbank users
    var REF_USERS = Database.database().reference().child("users")

    // Singleton pattern (Einzelstück Muster)
    static var shared: UserApi = UserApi()
    private init() {
    }

    // Aktuell eingeloggte User ID
    var CURRENT_USER_UID: String? {
        if let currentUserUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            return currentUserUid
        }
        return nil
    }

    // Aktuell eingeloggte User
    var CURRENT_USER: User? {
        if let currentUserUid = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            return currentUserUid
        }
        return nil
    }

    // Lade User mit der id
    func observeUser(uid: String, completion: @escaping (UserModel) -> Void) {
        REF_USERS.child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            let newUser = UserModel(dictionary: dic)
            completion(newUser)
        }
    }

    // Lade user ohne id
    func observeUser(completion: @escaping (UserModel) -> Void ) {
        REF_USERS.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            let user = UserModel(dictionary: dic)
            completion(user)
        }
    }

    // Lade den aktuellen User
    func observeCurrentUser(completion: @escaping (UserModel) -> Void ) {
        guard let currentUserUid = CURRENT_USER_UID else { return }
        REF_USERS.child(currentUserUid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            let currentUser = UserModel(dictionary: dic)
            completion(currentUser)
        }
    }

    // User im Suchfeld laden
    func queryUser(withText text: String, completion: @escaping(UserModel) -> Void ) {
        REF_USERS.queryOrdered(byChild: "username_lowercase").queryStarting(atValue: text).queryEnding(atValue: text + "\u{f8ff}").queryLimited(toLast: 5).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            snapshot.children.forEach({ (data) in
                let child = data as! DataSnapshot
                guard let dic = child.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                let user = UserModel(dictionary: dic)
                completion(user)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**Supplementary information**

We will add additional information if we have other missing information.
Since I often do not understand Swift in 4 weeks, I would like you to tell me with concrete code etc.

Reference material
[How to delete a child from Firebase (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749130/how-to-delete-a-child-from-firebase-swift)

Comment: There's way too much code here that doesn't seem related to the problem. Please look into [creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve the chance that someone will spot the problem and be able to help.

Comment: I will improve! Thank you!

Comment: Is this okay?Is there room for improvement yet?

Comment: There is lots of code dealing with observers, but nothing that deletes a node. So it's hard to know where you are stuck in deleting data and how the code you shared relates to that. Did you read the documentation on deleting data here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#delete_data? If so, where did you get stuck in implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wild guess at an answer as it's unclear how the OP determines which node to delete.

Let's assume a tableView is displayed in the UI and the user has swiped a row_to_delete. We will also assume we have an array of Post objects that have a 'key' property from a snapshot.

To then delete a post, retrieve the post from the dataSource array and get it's key. Then build a ref to that ans removeValue.

```
let postToDelete = postsArray[row_to_delete]
let postKey = postToDelete.key
let ref = your_firebase.child("posts").child(postKey)
ref.removeValue()
```