# Deleting a Node in Firebase (Swift) specified with ChildautoID

Tags: swift, firebase

I have seen a lot of similar questions online but they are straightforward in the sense the path of the node is clear and all is needed to remove the node is to include the ".removeValue" However in my case, the posts are all specified by a random ID (.ChildAutoID()) , generated when the post is being made. So when I try to specify the path for the node, it's confusing how to construct. [The following is how my JSON structure looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktu46.png)

In addition, [this is my code to delete the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9m3D.png)

However this wont work because the postID is random every time, so the path that is being deleted will never match the post I am aiming for. This question ([How to delete a child from Firebase (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749130/how-to-delete-a-child-from-firebase-swift)) is similar to what I am trying to achieve and the solution is said but there are a lot of missing pieces that I cant connect to apply to my situation. I am not sure how the user saves the postID and surpasses the Child. In addition to that I am not too sure how to go about checking to see if a post can only be deleted by its owner (comparing the current user ID with the userID in the post.

UPDATE:
I was able to delete the post by doing the following:
- Instead of having the node get specified by ChildbyAutoID I used a simple postID = UUID().uuidString
- I included another varliable in my JSON file named postID which is the same as the node: Look at the updated [JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF13.png)

Now in my Blog tableView, queried the PostID for the given cell at a particular Row and included it at the path for the deletion.

There are a couple restrictions:
- You can only delete one post (you need to leave the view and go back in to delete another view)

p.s. I am not sure what else to post in here. I also dont know if this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a node from firebase that has auto increment child id then you have to identify that node by any unique value present in your node that you want to delete, like here I have identified the node by date, I have inserted date in each of my messages node that has auto increment child id. If you have any confusion then please comment below I will be happy to assist you..

```
let chatReference: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts").child("Messages")
                    }
                    let date = "2018-11-26 09:56:08"

                    chatReference.queryOrdered(byChild: "date").queryEqual(toValue: date).observe(.childAdded, with: {  //to delete message filtered by unique date
                        snapshot in
                        snapshot.ref.removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, reference) in
                       //node successfully deleted
                        if error != nil {
                        print("There has been an error:\(String(describing: error))")
                        }
                        })
                    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was actually testing some things out, if you read my update, I believe we did something similar but I made a dynamic variable instead of a constant like you have (let data = ...) This way I can delete any post.

Comment: ok that's great.. I was also having same issue like you before and I solved it by doing it like this..

Comment: I am trying to find a way to compare the current user ID with the user id of a post, but since the userID in the post is String and the uid of the current user is User, I cant make the comparison, I tried to case the User to a String but I cant seem to get it to work, any ideas?

Comment: are you getting issue in comparison of uuid ?